# ag-chart-community treemap rendering empty root at each react component update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-charts-react

I am using react: "^18.2.0"

ag-charts-community: "^28.2.0"

I am aware that ag-grid offers a react wrapper  (AgChartsReact 'ag-charts-react')

However it seems to be performing arguably worse than the code snipped below.

Situation:
Every 1.5 seconds my component gets a new data update which I would like to display in my treemap.

The issue is that the treemap renders an empty "Root", before displaying the new Data

please note that the myData variable is as follows:

```
myData = { 
 label: "Root",
 children: [...someData]
}
```

Below is the code for my component

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useRef, useEffect} from "react"; 
import { MyDataContext } from "dataContext"; 
import { AgChart } from " ag-charts-community";
    
    export const TreeMap = () => {
        const { myData } = useContext(MyDataContext) // updates every 1.5 seconds
        const containerRef = useRef()
        const [myChartInstance,setMyChartInstance]= useState()
        const options = {
            data: myData,
            series: [
                {
                    type: "treemap"
                  // ...
                } 
            ]
        }
        useEffect(() => {
            const myChart = AgChart.create({
                ...options,
                container: containerRef.current
            })
            setMyChartInstance(myChart)
            return () => {
                myChart.destroy()
            }
        },[])
    
        useEffect(() => {
            // check if condition is met (currently throttling updates)
            // and update chart with newOptions
            if (myChartInstance && condition === true) {
                AgChart.updateDelta(myChartInstance, newOptions)
            }
         
        },[data])
    
        return (<div ref={myChartInstance} />) }
```

Can anyone help me understand if there is an issue in my component lifecycle or if the ag-charts-community treemap implementation has issues